# Dynamic dropdownbuttons

Tags: flutter, dart, android-widget

Im working on a small project for which i need a lot of drop down buttons, so i decided to make it dynamic ,so i created a separate class for the dropdownbutton , but im getting an error when i run it,
i dont know where the error is, is there any other efficient way of doing this?and where am i making the mistake

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "buttons.dart";

void main(){
  runApp(My_app());
}

class My_app extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _My_app();
  }
}

class _My_app extends State<My_app>{
  var color_list = ["RED","GREEN","BLUE"];
  var weight_list = ["300","400","800"];
  var color = [Colors.red,Colors.green,Colors.blue];
  var weight = [FontWeight.w300,FontWeight.w400,FontWeight.w800];
  var color_var = 0;
  var weight_var = 0;
  var milo = "RED" ;
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
      title:"Font Designer",
      home:Material(
        child:Center(
          child:Container(
            child:Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:40),
                      child:Dropy(color_list,color,color_var)
                    )
                  ]
                )
              ],
            )
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }

}
```

//buttons.dart

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class Dropy extends StatefulWidget{

  var listy;
  var power;
  var varie;

  Dropy(var k,var m,var n){
    this.listy = k;
    this.power = m;
    this.varie = n;
  }

  State<StatefulWidget> createState(){
    return _Dropy(this.listy,this.power,this.varie);
  }
}

class _Dropy extends State<Dropy>{

  var tex;
  var liy;
  var pow;
  var va;
  var male;

  _Dropy(var o,var p,var z){
    this.liy = o;
    this.pow = p;
    this.va = z;
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      items:liy.map((String etx) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: etx,
            child: Text(etx)
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (String milo){
        setState(() {
          this.va = this.liy.indexOf(male);
          male = milo;
        });
      },
      value: male,);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two package you can reference source code or directly use it 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/find_dropdown 
It also support search and validation

full example code

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:find_dropdown/find_dropdown.dart';

import 'user_model.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("FindDropdown Example")),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            FindDropdown(
              items: ["Brasil", "Itália", "Estados Unidos", "Canadá"],
              label: "País",
              onChanged: print,
              selectedItem: "Brasil",
              showSearchBox: false,
              validate: (String item) {
                if (item == null)
                  return "Required field";
                else if (item == "Brasil")
                  return "Invalid item";
                else
                  return null;
              },
            ),
            FindDropdown<UserModel>(
              label: "Nome",
              onFind: (String filter) => getData(filter),
              searchBoxDecoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Search",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
              onChanged: (UserModel data) => print(data),
            ),
            FindDropdown<UserModel>(
              label: "Personagem",
              onFind: (String filter) => getData(filter),
              onChanged: (UserModel data) {
                print(data);
              },
              dropdownBuilder: (BuildContext context, UserModel item) {
                return Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Theme.of(context).dividerColor),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  child: (item?.avatar == null)
                      ? ListTile(
                          leading: CircleAvatar(),
                          title: Text("No item selected"),
                        )
                      : ListTile(
                          leading: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(item.avatar),
                          ),
                          title: Text(item.name),
                          subtitle: Text(item.createdAt.toString()),
                        ),
                );
              },
              dropdownItemBuilder:
                  (BuildContext context, UserModel item, bool isSelected) {
                return Container(
                  decoration: !isSelected
                      ? null
                      : BoxDecoration(
                          border:
                              Border.all(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                  child: ListTile(
                    selected: isSelected,
                    title: Text(item.name),
                    subtitle: Text(item.createdAt.toString()),
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(item.avatar),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<List<UserModel>> getData(filter) async {
    var response = await Dio().get(
      "http://5d85ccfb1e61af001471bf60.mockapi.io/user",
      queryParameters: {"filter": filter},
    );

    var models = UserModel.fromJsonList(response.data);
    return models;
  }
}
```

[image]

or use package https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_formfield

full example code of use

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dropdown_formfield/dropdown_formfield.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _myActivity;
  String _myActivityResult;
  final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _myActivity = '';
    _myActivityResult = '';
  }

  _saveForm() {
    var form = formKey.currentState;
    if (form.validate()) {
      form.save();
      setState(() {
        _myActivityResult = _myActivity;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Dropdown Formfield Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Form(
          key: formKey,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: DropDownFormField(
                  titleText: 'My workout',
                  hintText: 'Please choose one',
                  value: _myActivity,
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _myActivity = value;
                    });
                  },
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _myActivity = value;
                    });
                  },
                  dataSource: [
                    {
                      "display": "Running",
                      "value": "Running",
                    },
                    {
                      "display": "Climbing",
                      "value": "Climbing",
                    },
                    {
                      "display": "Walking",
                      "value": "Walking",
                    },
                    {
                      "display": "Swimming",
                      "value": "Swimming",
                    },
                    {
                      "display": "Soccer Practice",
                      "value": "Soccer Practice",
                    },
                    {
                      "display": "Baseball Practice",
                      "value": "Baseball Practice",
                    },
                    {
                      "display": "Football Practice",
                      "value": "Football Practice",
                    },
                  ],
                  textField: 'display',
                  valueField: 'value',
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Save'),
                  onPressed: _saveForm,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: Text(_myActivityResult),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]